# Как найти проблему в .exe сделанном при помощи pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Имеется python-скрипт который был написан мною в IDE pyCharm, при запуске pyCharm код отрабатывает как надо.
Если я запускаю скрипт из командной строки `>python OpcSender.py` всё отрабатывает также идеально.

При помощи pyinstaller я собрал проект в исполняемый файл OpcSender.exe.
При запуске OpcSender.exe начинается выполнение программы, но она не работает корректно, значения с ОРС не считываются.
Что делает программа:

```
Подключаемся к ОРС:
import OpenOPC

opc = OpenOPC.client()
servers = opc.servers()
print(servers)
try:
    opc.connect(servers[0])
except:
    print("не удалось подключиться к ОРС - серверу")

while:
    try:
       #обрабатываем полученнные значения
    except:
        print("error read item")
        opc.close()
```

Также прикреплю скриншоты работы программы.
Это работа OpcSender.exe
[image: OpcSender.exe]
Это работа скрипта OpcSender.py
[image: OpcSender.py]
Подскажите **какие** могут быть **шаги к решению** этой проблемы?

Answer (score 0):

все что могу сказать это во время экспортирования в .exe убрать --noconsole и отловить появление ошибки(она появляется на мгновение, и если сделать prt sc, то при везении можно понять где ошибка), мне помогало не один раз

Comment: я не использовал такой флаг. Плюс в описании написано, что программа начинает выполняться, но работает не так как скрипт запущенный из под консоли или из под pyCharm